# Shrove Tuesday - what alcohol can I serve with my pancakes?

Tags: pairing, holidays

So,  we have [shrove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrove_Tuesday) tuesday.  But what should we serve with our pancakes?  I am thinking a nice [cognac](http://www.cognac.com/) .

If you don't know how to make a pancake, you can learn [here](http://www.foodnetwork.com/how-to/articles/how-to-make-perfect-pancakes).  Then add the drink of your choice.  What is your choice?

Comment: @Monica Cellio♦.  Great tag edits - I couldn't seem to get them quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people might like [wine](http://www.drvino.com/2011/02/22/pancakes-wine-pairing-week/) with their pancakes on Shrove Tuesday.

Seeing that Shrove Tuesday is the day before [Lent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lent), please allow me to make two recommendations.

My first recommendation would be [mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mead). Mead would be a fitting drink to ease the knowledge that tomorrow is the start of the traditional 40 days of fasting.

My second drink would be a nice good bottle of **Rauchbier** or "smoke beer". In today's way of fasting during Lent alcohol is no longer a forbidden food, so any left over could be consumed during Lent.

> Rauchbier, or “smoke beer,” is made using malts that have been dried over fire—-thus gaining the smoky taste of cured meats like ham and bacon. At one time all beers malts were produced over fire, but in medieval Bavaria beers of this type came to be associated with Lent when the rich, smoky tones of meat were dearly missed. There is, of course, an official blessing for beer (“Bless, O Lord, this creature beer . . . ”) which one may safely assume is more efficacious in the original Latin: ” Benedic, Domine, creaturam istam cerevisiae, quam ex adipe frumenti producere dignatus es: ut sit remedium salutare humano generi, et praesta per invocationem nominis tui sancti; ut, quicumque ex ea biberint, sanitatem corpus et animae tutelam percipiant. Per Christum Dominum nostrum. Amen.” - [Ten Weird, Wonderful Foods for Lent](https://www.firstthings.com/blogs/firstthoughts/2013/02/the-ten-most-wonderful-and-strange-foods-for-lent)

Comment: Great background to the question, as is always the case with your answers.  I like the idea that alcohol is no longer a forbidden food - or we would have to shut the site for 40 days!

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to stick with the Lenten theme and wanted to stay traditional and you lived in Munich Germany and you were a monk working at a monastery, you would be drinking [Doppelbock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bock) beer. I'm not a big fan of beer in the morning, but hey it's up to you.

I would more likely be drinking a glass of Champagne, or even better a [Mimosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimosa_(cocktail)) or the best morning drink, a [Bloody Mary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody_Mary_(cocktail))!